# All async Jquery/asp.net ajax calls blocked by one

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have a JQuery app that makes 4 async calls to 4 asp.net web services, each on a seperate timer.

When I add a Thread.Sleep(10000) command to one of the web services, all of the web services take 10 seconds to return.

Is there a way to avoid this?  Does it have something to do with the application pool's threading model?

Comment: Where are you adding the Thread.Sleep?

Comment: Can we see the code? Are you launching each request on  a new thread?

Comment: I am adding Thread.Sleep at the beginning of once of the web service calls in the asp.net c# code.

Comment: This is a huge project, and I have not had time to create a simplified example, so, I can not post the code.

Comment: The calls are definitely async.  I can see in fiddler that all the requests go out, are pending for 10 seconds than return roughly in unison.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into the problem described here: http://www.openajax.org/runtime/wiki/The_Two_HTTP_Connection_Limit_Issue

If this is the case, you may want to ensure you only have a single long-lived connection.

Comment: hmmm.  I would expect that the single 10 second web service would "Lock up" one of the two connections, leaving the other connection free to service the other 3 request that are no being blocked by Thread.Sleep.

Comment: I would normally expect this to happen too, but I've seen browsers leave a connection open to content downloads that should be finished before now... they can behave very oddly sometimes.  Is your code running in window.onload or from some other event?  Are you sure your page finishes loading correctly?